# Confusion on which parts of MDS will be removed in BES

Tags: blackberry

Can someone clarify which parts of MDS are being deprecated.

1. MDS Connection services. *I assume this is not being removed?  Otherwise, how does a native app make calls to http servers through BES?*
2. MDS Integration services.  *Sounds like this is being removed?*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on these links [Blackberry MDS](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/7335/BB_MDS_267706_11.jsp) and the other is for [Blackberry MDS Integration Service](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/7325/BB_MDS_Integration_Service_466371_11.jsp) . You can explore this site for more information.

Comment: my pleasure if i helped you... you can accept it as answer so others will get help from it thanks.